# Best approach to conditionally update nodes in d3.js force graphs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, d3.js

I am working on an interactive timeline using d3.js composed of a force layout and a slider. My data is encoded to JSON from MySQL. As the slider moves, we want nodes to appear/disappear depending on their JSON values. Repeatedly calling the database every tick of the slider is pretty costly and a big no-no. I've seen examples of JSON queries but I haven't seen one implemented in d3.json.

What's the optimal approach to conditionally remove/add nodes on the graph? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to get all the filtered out nodes(i.e. the nodes you don't want to be shown based on your slider values) and make their display:none.

Comment: Oh my. I've thought of that solution before I read about d3's enters and exits and have completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Another approach would be to change the JSON. And call the update method as shown in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288.
The update method will ensure to remove the nodes and its links using exit.